# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser beginner

Tags: php

Hello I've succesfully parsed some tables from an html page using this code:

```
foreach($html->find('table') as $table) {
echo '<table>';
echo $table->innertext;
echo '</table>';
}
```

Now I'd like to parse some more code, look at the source html below:

```
<h5>.....</h5>
<table>.....</table>
<h5>.....</h5>
<table>.....</table>
<h5>.....</h5>
<table>.....</table>
```

I tried this code:

```
foreach($html->find('h5') as $h5) {
echo '<h5>';
echo $h5->innertext;
echo '</h5>';
}
foreach($html->find('table') as $table) {
echo '<table>';
echo $table->innertext;
echo '</table>';
}
```

This is the output:

```
<h5>.....</h5>
<h5>.....</h5>
<h5>.....</h5>
<table>.....</table>
<table>.....</table>
<table>.....</table>
```

How can I do to preserve the original order?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You have to get and loop over all nodes at once

```
foreach($html->find('h5, table') as $node) { // or ->find('*')
    echo '<' . $node->tag . '>'; // $node->tag = 'h5' for a h5-element, and so on
    echo $node->innertext;
    echo '</' . $node->tag . '>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! It looks like it's working as intended. One more question: how can I add a class to table tags?

Comment: I suggest you read the [simplehtmldom documentation](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) (although it is very minimal...). You can easily read out an node's class with `$tableClass = $node->class`

Comment: Thanks I was able to add classes with this code:
    foreach($html->find('h5, .table') as $node) {
    echo '<' . $node->tag . ' class="live-data">'; // $node->tag = 'h5' for a h5-element, and so on
    echo $node->innertext;
    echo '</' . $node->tag . '>';

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I was able to add classes with this code:

```
foreach($html->find('h5, .table') as $node) {
echo '<' . $node->tag . ' class="myclass">';
echo $node->innertext;
echo '</' . $node->tag . '>';
```

Comment: `.table`? I don't know this parser but this looks like a class selector.

Comment: Yes I only needed to parse tables with class="table".